# How to retrieve the current number of line in a PRTF

Tags: data-structures, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have to modify a program that's printing some data. 
Now the task is to write a new way of how to begin a new page when a certain line number is reached. Since at the end of the spool file some constant data are printed and they must not be seperated by a new page.

The current way is to increment a counter. But this is very bad way since when printing a barcode, I don't know how large (how many lines) this barcode is. And, I want to achieve a way I can implement on all programs so I don't have to test and get the size for every barcode by myself.

I know that there is data structure for display files that tells me the cursor location. So - as I understand this - there must be a possibility to to the same with PRTF and the current line number.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Printer File information data structure? There is a current line number in there. But I don't know if it is populated for AFPDS or IPDS data streams.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the File Information Data Structure (INFDS) to get the information you need.

```
 FQSYSPRT   O    F  132        PRINTER OFLIND(*INOF)   
 F                                     INFDS(OutputFDS)
 F                                     PRTCTL(PrtCtlDS)

 D*File Information Data Structure                                                          
 D OutputFDS       DS                                                                       
 D**Open Feedback Area                                                                      
 D  ROWS                 152    153I 0                                                      
 D  OVERFLOW             188    189I 0                                                      
 D                                                                                          
 D**Printer Feedback Area                                                                   
 D  CUR_LINE             367    368I 0                                      Current line num
 D  CUR_PAGE             369    372I 0                                      Current page cnt


 D*Printer Control Data Structure           
 D PrtCtlDS        DS                       
 D  pSpacing               1     12         
 D  pSpcBefore             1      3A        
 D  pSpcAfter              4      6A        
 D  pSkpBefore             7      9A        
 D  pSkpAfter             10     12A        
 D  pLineNbr              13     15S 0
```

You can get the line number from the printer control data structure (PRTCTL) as well, but you often will also want to know the rows and the overflow line in your situation and that can only be found in the INFDS.

Comment: Good answer, but the OP is dealing with either IPDS or AFPDS printer files since he's printing a barcode.  As Mark commented on the post, I don't believe line# is accurate once you start dealing with non-text data.